# How to make a cross symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I found the post on [Small cross and small upside down cross symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120400/small-cross-and-small-upside-down-cross-symbols) but this did not work for me using the default font in LaTeX. I am hoping for a way to print a special character that is a cross. Alt+0134 does not display, I already tried that. I am open to another font just for the cross (not for the entire document), but I don't know which one will display the symbol. I am most interested in how to make a cross similar to the one circled in the image below, but it would be neat to learn to make any others also.

[image: Cross pictures]

Comment: Does `\Cross` in `\usepackage{marvosym}` at [Table 293: Other marvosym Symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and `Table 248: bbding Crosses and Plusses
` work for you

Comment: Finding out whether the font has the symbol depends on your OS. There are many tools that can display all the symbols in a font. Using a particular font for part of a document is covered here: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)

Comment: @texenthusiast please make that comment an answer.

Comment: @Dan Ok Done,expanded my comment and added Alan Munn's comment inside my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Alan-munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) suggested "Finding out whether the font has the symbol depends on your OS. There are many tools that can display all the symbols in a font. Using a particular font for part of a document is covered here: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document)"

Any of my symbol search starts at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html
and later [symbols-a4.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). I got it from `symbols-a4.pdf` link.

**Table 293: Other `marvosym` Symbols: Page 90**

`\Cross` in `\usepackage{marvosym}`.
It is important to note that this symbol only works in text mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt,convert=false,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\Cross 
\end{document}
```

[image: Cross symbol]

**Table 248: `bbding` Crosses and Plusses: Page 76**

```
\documentclass[12pt,convert=false,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\Cross  ~\CrossOpenShadow  ~\PlusOutline
 ~\Plus   ~\CrossMaltese     ~\PlusCenterOpen
\end{document}
```

[image: Several cross symbols]

**Table 249: `pifont` Crosses and Plusses:Page 77**

```
\documentclass[12pt,convert=false,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\ding{57}  ~\ding{59} ~\ding{61} ~\ding{63}
~\ding{58}  ~\ding{60} ~\ding{62} ~\ding{64}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Build your own.  You can change the dimensions based on the four parameters I provide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\thickness{.2ex}
\def\crossheight{1.6ex}
\def\crosswidth{1ex}
\def\barheight{1ex}
\def\plaincross{\bottominset{\rule{\crosswidth}{\thickness}}
                       {\rule{\thickness}{\crossheight}}{\barheight}{0ex}}
\begin{document}
x\plaincross X
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you add more horizontal space so that the cross is not so close to the next letter?

Comment: @R.B.Jawad Immediately before the closing brace of the definition of `\plaincross`, you can add `\kern1pt` or some other suitable length.  For space on the left side, add the kern immediately after the opening brace of the definition.

Answer (score 5):

[Overlaying elements using `\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764) you can build the cross as a horizontal and vertical bar/`\rule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cross}[1][1pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}}% Vertical bar
\begin{document}
This is a cross \cross. This is a thinner cross \cross[.4pt].
\end{document}
```

The default width of the cross is `1pt`, but this can be changed through a simple optional argument.

Comment: `\ooalign` is buggy, it only takes the height of the first symbol and the depth of the second for the composed character. In this case, it is fixed by using the vertical bar first, because the composed symbol does not have a depth.

Answer (score -2):

In order to draw your symbol, follow the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\Cross 
\end{document}
```

This symbol only works in text mode.

An important resource that you might want to check out is Detexify.  It allows you to draw different symbols, and the program compiles the list of symbols similar to the image that has been drawn.  The link is below.
http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: This does not add value, since evreything of your answer is already included in Texenthusiast’s answer (one line could perhaps be added as comment: “`\Cross` from package `marvosym` works only in text mode.”).

Comment: I would respectfully disagree.  By your own admission, Texenthusiast’s answer does not contain important information that my answer does.  Also, Texenthusiast’s answer is more difficult to read and understand than my answer.  Thus, my comment does add value.