# Is there a religious symbols font collection?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I can find collections for chess, cards, etc. But could not locate a religious fonts collection.

Comment: What do you mean by religious fonts? Like crosses?

Comment: @Francis yes, crosses, David's star etc. I can find individual ones  by searching for "cross" in the comprehensive list, but cannot find a collection. What goes for crescent symbol or other symbols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you’re using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use any Unicode symbol you like – provided that your font has it. The font *Segoe UI Symbol* (which is a Windows system font I think), for instance, supports a decent portion of the symbols listed at *[Cultural, political, and religious symbols in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural,_political,_and_religious_symbols_in_Unicode)* on Wikipedia:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}% also not bad
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\begin{document}\Huge
࿕ ࿖ ࿗ ࿘ Ⓐ ☘ ☠ ☥ ☦ ☧ ☨ ☩ ☪ ☫ ☬ ☭ ☮ ☯ ☸ ☹ ☺ ☻ ♡ ♥ ♰ ♱
⚜ ⛤ ⛥ ⛦ ⛧ ✊ ✌ ✝ ✞ ✟ ✠ ✡ ❤ ⸙ 卍 卐 ﷲ      
              
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Since you were asking for a collection in particular, I’d point you to the aforementioned Wikipedia article. If you’re looking for a specific symbol, check out search sites like http://www.unicode-table.com or http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode, which also provide character tables – there’s specifically the Unicode section *U+2626 – U+262F Religious and political symbols*. Finally, if you’re looking for a font with broad Unicode support, Wikipedia saves the day once again with the articles [*(List of) Unicode fonts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts) and [*List of Typefaces – Unicode fonts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Unicode_fonts).

Answer (score 8):

The standard package `pifont` provides three Christian-style crosses and the Star of David. I could do with a crescent for Islam, as well, and some other things but am not sure where to find them right now:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
  \ding{61} \ding{62} \ding{63} \ding{65}
\end{document}
```

[image: religious dings]

`wasysym` offers an alternative `\davidsstar`:

[image: <code>wasysym</code> Star of David]

`bbding` offers crosses and Stars of David but only in metafont format.

`marvosym` enables multiple symbol commands, including `\Cross \Ankh \CeltCross \Yinyang`:

[image: <code>marvosym</code> religious symbols]

I find it rather odd I can't find anything for Islam given the range of symbols in the Comprehensive list. Am I looking wrong?

## Update

Anyway, in case anybody has a use for them, I post the following `tikz` `pic`s which can be used to create two varieties of cross, a Star of David and a crescent/star symbol. Each `pic` requires a single argument corresponding to the size.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

  \tikzset{
    croes0/.pic={%
      \draw [line width=.2*#1, inner sep=0pt, pic actions] (0,.5*#1) -- (0,-.5*#1) (-.3*#1,.2*#1) -- (.3*#1,.2*#1);\
    },
    croes/.pic={%
      \draw [line width=.1*#1, inner sep=0pt, pic actions] (.075*#1,.45*#1) |- (.25*#1,.25*#1) |- (.075*#1,.1*#1) |- (-.075*#1,-.45*#1) |- (-.25*#1,.1*#1) |- (-.075*#1,.25*#1) -| (-.075*#1,.45*#1) -- cycle;
    },
    seren2/.pic={%
      \node (cylch seren) [circle, line width=0pt, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1] {};
      \foreach \i in {90, -54, -126, 18, 162}
      \coordinate (seren\i) at (node cs:name=cylch seren, angle=\i);
      \draw [fill, pic actions] (seren-126) -- (seren90) -- (seren-54) -- (seren162) -- (seren18)  -- cycle;
    },
    seren/.pic={%
      \node (cylch seren) [circle, line width=.1*#1, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1] {};
      \foreach \i in {90, -30, -150, -90, 30, 150}
      \coordinate (seren\i) at (node cs:name=cylch seren, angle=\i);
      \draw [line width=.1*#1, pic actions] (seren90) -- (seren-30) -- (seren-150) -- cycle (seren-90) -- (seren30) -- (seren150) -- cycle;
    },
    cilgant seren/.pic={%
      \path [fill, even odd rule, line width=.1*#1, pic actions] circle [radius=.5*#1] {} [xshift=.1*#1, draw=white, line width=.01*#1] circle [radius=.4*#1] {};
      \pic at (.5*#1,0) {seren2=.4*#1};
    },
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [red] at (0,0) {croes0=12.5pt};
    \pic [orange] at (.5,0) {croes=12.5pt};
    \pic [green] at (1,0) {seren=10pt};
    \pic [blue] at (1.5,0) {cilgant seren=10pt};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Faith in <code>tikz</code>]

## EDIT

**Do NOT name your pics.** That is, do **NOT** write something like `\pic (pic name) [blue] {cilgant seren=10pt};` else the symbol will **NOT** be drawn correctly. I'm not sure why this is, but it certainly is for at least some of the symbols such as the crescent-star. Since there is no point in naming them, not doing so is the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

it depends, what do you expect with religious fonts. At [How to make a cross symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128060/how-to-make-a-cross-symbol-in-latex) there are some crosses from `marvosym`.