# Strange Cross Symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I can't draw a particular cross symbol in LaTeX.  I tried drawing it in Dextify, but that didn't recognize the symbol.  I don't even know what it is called.  Any help with the name or the code is appreciated.  An image is below.  [image]

Comment: That looks like a variation of the [orthodox cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_cross).

Comment: aka "byzantine cross".  It is a Christian religious icon, where the center bar signifies the cross on which Jesus hung.  The top bar represents the "INRI" plaque set there by Pilate identifying Jesus as "King  of the Jews", and the bottom bar represents the rest upon which his feet lay.  It is tilted in the direction of the adjacent crucified thief who confessed Him Lord.

Comment: i am reasonably sure that this symbol isn't in unicode (yet).  if there is a compelling reason (for technical documents) that it should be included, and citations to published uses can be provided, i will be happy to submit it for consideration.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Unicode 2626, according to http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132855/is-there-a-religious-symbols-font-collection

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am 100% sure that I have seen this symbol used in technical writings.  That is why I was surprised that Dextify did not have this listed.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- right you are, 2626 it is.  (i just didn't check all the right places.)  it wasn't on the list of symbols requested by the stipub participants, so wasn't included in the stix fonts.  (the only symbol in the 2600 block included in the stix fonts is 2621, the "dangerous bend".  we know why *that*'s there.)

Comment: @Mathematician -- detexify, as far as i know, hasn't yet expanded to include the wider unicode repertoire provided by the stix and other similarly comprehensive fonts (e.g. cambria); i'm sure it will happen, but it'll be a big job.  and since this symbol isn't in the stix fonts (don't know about cambria or others), it probably won't be first on the list.  if a font can be identified that includes it -- and has latex support --, a suggestion to the detexify maintainer(s) might help move things along.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed, the placement of the "dangerous curve" is very apropos, in light of Luke 3:5.

Comment: www.shapecatcher.com doesn't catch it either for me (unicode tool similar to detexify by the same people).  Pasting it into http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ gives the unicode value but no TeX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer at [Is there a religious symbols font collection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132855/is-there-a-religious-symbols-font-collection), a XeLaTeX solution that grabs unicode character 2626 from a font that has the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\begin{document}\Huge
\symbol{"2626}
\end{document}
```

[image]

egreg suggests `FreeSerif` font as a preferred alternative to `Segoe UI Symbol`, because of its distribution with TeX Live, and its general availability at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/, in the form of `freefont-otf-20100919.zip`.  With `FreeSerif`, the result looks like this:

[image]

Otherwise, like Herbert's answer, it can be constructed, in this case, with stacks, where I create the macro `\byz` (EDITED to add kerning).  The rule thickness is controlled by `\rlwd`.  If reset from 0.4pt to 0.7pt, the symbol becomes more bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\rlwd{.4pt}
\def\byz{\kern.5pt\def\stacktype{L}%
 \stackon[0.65ex]{%
  \stackon[1.4ex]{%
    \stackon[1.1ex]{\rule{\rlwd}{1.8ex}}{\rule{1.4ex}{\rlwd}}%
  }{\rule{0.8ex}{\rlwd}}%
 }{\rotatebox{-20}{\rule{0.8ex}{\rlwd}}}%
\kern1pt}
\begin{document}
A\byz$\Omega$
\def\rlwd{.7pt}\par
A\byz$\Omega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe FreeSerif is a better choice instead of Segoe UI Symbol, because the former is included in TeX Live (and I guess also in MiKTeX).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\def\StrangeCross{%
  \unitlength=1pt\thicklines
 \begin{picture}(20,30)
 \put(10,0){\line(0,1){30}}
 \put(5,15){\line(5,-2){10}}
 \put(0,20){\line(1,0){20}}
 \put(5,25){\line(1,0){10}}
  \end{picture}}
\begin{document}

\StrangeCross

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is an actual symbol in LaTeX so I don't have to draw it each time I write it?

Comment: no, I never saw such a symbol. However, it is really simple to create it with MetaFont. Then you can use it like a normal font.

Answer (score 0):

Draw it with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\StrangeCross{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw (0,0.8) -- (0,-0.8);
    \draw (-0.3,0.5) -- (0.3,0.5);
    \draw (-0.6,0.2) -- (0.6,0.2);
    \draw (-0.3,-0.2) -- (0.3,-0.4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\begin{document}

\StrangeCross

\end{document}
```

[image]