# The abbreviation "viz."

Tags: symbols, unicode

The word *viz.* that is often met in English texts, is an abbreviation for *videlicet*, a latin word meaning *namely* or *as follows*. It is constructed from the first letters *vi* and an symbol for the suffix *-et*. So where comes the *z* from? Originally, the suffix was abbreviated using a medieval [tironian symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%81%8A) that looks like that: ⁊.
It has unicode `U+204A`. The *z* is used because of the limitations of old typewriters. I haven't found anything useful so far to use it in LaTeX. [This link](http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B204A) states that there is nothing in LaTeX for `U+204A`. Does anyone know how to use the original symbol in a document?

Comment: check if you find it with http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Linux Libertine O (the OpenType font) has it.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with typewriters. Typewriters didn't become common until the end of the 19th century, and if they are the culprit here, then you'd expect to see ⁊ a lot in typeset books from before the 20th century. I don't think I've seen it at all, actually.

Comment: @Sverre. Actually, the mentioned wikipedia page states that this symbol is still in use in Ireland and in Scotland and that it was used in german books throughout the 19th century.

Comment: You don't mention the context but, unless you're actually discussing the history of the abbreviation, you should just write "viz", with an ordinary "z". If you write the original symbol without explanation, people won't understand it (and won't be able to Google it, either!)

Comment: @DavidRicherby. Yes you are right. My question was merely motivated by curiosity.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If the document is electronic, they can copy and paste, they'll be able to Google it, and hopefully it will bring them here. :)

Comment: @Sverre A more likely culprit would be moveable type sets, rather than typewriters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done with XeLaTeX.  Of course, you can pick a different UNICODE font available to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\begin{document}
vi\symbol{"204A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @V.Rossetto I had practice yesterday with a related answer.  At that answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182814/strange-cross-symbol-in-latex/182824#182824, egreg suggested the `FreeSerif` font as an alternative, as well.

Answer (score 5):

Just in order to show the other mentioned fonts:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\vizF}{vi{\setmainfont{FreeSerif}\symbol{"204A}}}
\newcommand{\vizL}{vi{\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}\symbol{"204A}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\vizF{},\\ \vizL{},\\ viz.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version could be `\newcommand{\vizD}{vi{\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}\symbol{"204A}}}` but that looks to ugly to do a screen shot.

Comment: If one wants to typeset early characters, [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/) is one of the best fonts. See [MUFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Unicode_Font_Initiative) for additional information about typesetting medieval texts.