# 'Tironian Sign Et' in LaTeX

Tags: unicode

How do I insert a 'Tironian Sign Et' in LaTeX?

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/204a/index.htm

or is there a symbol that looks just like it?

Comment: This symbol is addressed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182920/the-abbreviation-viz

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Is it possible to insert the symbol somehow in the default LaTeX engine (instead of XeTeX, which I can do)?

Comment: Will you be frequently using it as part of streaming text (i.e., will it require kerning relative to adjacent letters), or will it only occasionally appear as a semi-independent entity.  If the latter, you could save a cropped image of the symbol, and employ it as an include-graphic in the manner described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, this might work. Is there a way to define a character in the LaTeX code?

Comment: If by "define" you mean create as a font character, not as a graphic, then one would need to edit/modify/create a font itself that supports the character.  Some fonts do possess this glyph, but they are not supported fonts of latex, and thus are inaccessible to plain LaTeX, only via XeLaTeX.  Alternately, one could use something like `tikz` to draw it from scratch, but I suspect that would be similar in many regards to using it as a graphic.

Comment: \usepackage{amsfonts} $\mathfrak{7}$ looks like the symbol, except the tail is too long, is there a uncomplicated way to crop this?

Comment: Will you be using it as a math symbol (requires subscript sizes etc.) or as a text symbol?

Comment: If text, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,trimclip} 
\def\viz{\setbox0=\hbox{$\mathfrak{7}$}\clipbox{0pt \dp0 0pt 0pt}{$\mathfrak{7}$}}
\begin{document}
vi\viz\par
\Huge vi\viz
\end{document}`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the compiler you use (and your operating system). In XeLaTeX, for example, you can directly enter the Unicode character (or copy it from a chart) using your OS's means (e.g. combining keys under a Linux running KDE; `<Alt>+<+>+[Hex-Code]` in Windows if enabled).

Other compilers ('standard' LaTeX) may not natively support Unicode input.
See [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex?rq=1).