# Russian crosses

Tags: symbols

How may I reproduce a three beamed or two beamed [Russian Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Orthodox_cross)?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182814/strange-cross-symbol-in-latex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Unfortunately I don't understand how to implement Unicodes.

Comment: To employ unicode, you have to be using xelatex or lualatex, instead of pdflatex.  If you are, and if you are using a font that supports the cross, `\symbol{"2626}` is sufficient to invoke it.  If you are using pdflatex, one of the other approaches shown in those answers could be used: `stackengine`, `pict2e`, or `tikz`.